# How to display the rendered HTML of the code in Github Repository

Tags: html, github, github-pages

This is an old problem but I fail to find satisfied answer. I create a repository with some html files. When I open it, I see the html source code instead of the rendered version. The example is here: [Example](https://github.com/liaochunyang/Test_html/blob/main/circle.html).

What I want to do is that I see the rendered html webpage when I open the html files in my repository (not source code). I searched the answer online, some people said that it's impossible since Github force it to source code. Is it correct?

I know Github page and https://htmlpreview.github.io/, but they are not what I expected. The reason is that they try to create a new url link. I think that RawGit does the similar thing.

Do you have any idea to solve my problem? Or you can confirm that my idea is infeasible. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi user387147. This looks like a well-formed and reasonable question so I will try to help you for a few minutes thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you are going to need to use Github Pages:

https://pages.github.com/

They have a nice tutorial set up.

Comment: Yes that looks like a good solution. I will propose another one just for the sake of completeness, thank you Ben.